# use of this in constructor in refrence with dependencies injection in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, constructor

I was checking Angular Official documents and other blogs and see 2 different kinds of syntax for DI when using within the constructor, sometimes they use `this` and sometimes no use of `this`. which one is correct?

I know we need to use `this` in any other method of the class but why we do not use `this` in the constructor. or just `private` and `public` identifier makes the difference to use of `this`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


class NameService {
  getName () {
    return "Angular";
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Favourite framework: {{ name }}</h1>'
})
class AppComponent {
  name: string;

  constructor(nameService: NameService) {
    this.name = nameService.getName(); // do not use this

  }

  otherMethod() {
    this.nameService.getName(); // use this
  }
}
```

somewhere I have seen people using this within the constructor. here one of [the example](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#optional-dependencies)

```
constructor(@Optional() private logger: Logger) {
  if (this.logger) {
    this.logger.log(some_message); // using this
  }
}
```

so when do we use this and when not? or we are using this in later example because of `@Optional` decorators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all about Typescript. When you use `public`, `private` or `protected` on a constructor parameters as follows

```js
constructor(private logger: Logger) {}
```

In reality, Typescript creates a field with the same name and set it for you.
So, instead of writing following code you could simply write the code above

```js
private logger: Logger;

constructor(logger: Logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
}
```

Since, you already wrote `private logger`, you can simply use your field with `this`. It does not really matter how you use it within constructor.

There is a [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) where you can try this out and see it yourself. Whatever you type in the left box will be converted into plain JS (ES5) in the right box.

`@Optional` decorator just tells Angular that it is OK if it cannot find that object to inject.

**Rule of thumb:**

If you use `private`, `protected` or `public` on a any field and want to use it, always use `this` (within constructor)

If you didn’t mark the field with any of the keywords above, you cannot use `this` and cannot access that object outside of constructor.

If you need to access a property/method of a class, you HAVE to use `this`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but still confused whether to use `this` or not within the constructor?

Comment: but the default keyword is `public`. isn't it? but it throw error in angular and asked to set `private`. btw this thumb rule only applicable in constructor body only. any other method of the class must access the service only via `this` only. is that right?

Comment: There is no default keyword. If you don't explicitly define it, typescript will not create a field for you. Also, yes if you need to access any property of a class, you HAVE to use `this`. Within constructor, you don't need to use `this` because it is also a parameter of the constructor.

Comment: that makes perfect sense. Thanks one again.